# Twitter Streaming API - combine two predicates

Tags: twitter, twitter-feed

I'd like my Twitter Streaming API to catch all tweets mentioned using some #HashTag within the USA.  However, if I use the filter.json service specifying location= &track=, then I get the collective OR.  I believe I read somewhere on Stack Overflow that it's by design, but I don't still have that reference.

Is it possible to combine those using AND?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have the API deliver only tweets that match both conditions (AND), but you can collect tweets for either condition (OR), and then only use or save the tweets that match both conditions.

Comment: Well, not what I was hoping for, but okay.  Thanks!